# Secure RavenDb Management Studio on Server

Tags: ravendb

I have created a website in IIS for RavenDb on my server. I currently can access Raven Studio on 127.0.0.10 but I would also like to make the server accessible on the public IP. Is there any way of securing the Management Studio so it asks for a username/password before I can access it?

I have set Raven/AnonymousAccess to none but I can't seem to figure out how to set a username/password combination to log in.

**Update**

Ok I've worked it out. It's not actually a RavenDb setting it's configured in IIS (Thanks Fitzchack). After creating the RavenDb IIS website I took the following steps:

1. Create a windows user (RavenDbAdmin)
2. Disable Anonymous authentication for the website
3. Enable Windows authentication for the website

When now accessing the site on the public server IP it will ask for a password first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RavenDB uses windows accounts by default (OAuth is supported too), so you would need to create a windows account and use its credentials in order to log into RavenDB.

Just for another layer of security, you can also restrict IIS website itself, which will force you to login twice in the studio. This is not required, but this is a nice option to always have.

Comment: Will this basic idea work when using the Database from a remote app? Or is this only really for the management Studio?

Comment: This will work all, the Management Studio is an output of the server like the actual data is.

Comment: what about linux?